# I want to get count of null from each column of mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to get the null count from each MySQL table column. I do not want to hardcode for a specific table. This means if I change the table name in the query and it will give me the null count of all the columns of that table

Comment: I think `where column is null` will do that.

Comment: *I want* is not a question. Please share what have you tried so far and why isn't working .

Comment: i have tried 'SELECT COUNT(IFNULL(column_name_1, 1)), COUNT(IFNULL(column_name_2, 1)) FROM deals;' but each time i have to write all column_name. Is there any way to automate it by query

Comment: I can get the column name of the table using this query SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='table_name';

Comment: You'll have to write dynamic SQL that creates the query from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: It should just be `COUNT(column1), COUNT(column2), ...`. `COUNT(columnname)` returns the count of non-null values.

Comment: I know but how can I write a dynamic query which gets the columns name from the query apply an aggregate function to all columns?

Comment: I tried SELECT sum(if(column1 is null, 1, 0)), sum(if(column2 is null, 1, 0)) FROM app_events;
it gives me the correct null count but wants to add columns name dynamically